# How do I reduce the amount of variables and if statements in this code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, repeat

What would be the best method to reduce the amount of code used?
Eventually I will have around 20 buttons so it seems unnecessary to write the variable and the if statements out this many times.
Can someone please suggest an approach to this with reduced, cleaner code?
Would it help to put the variables into an array?

```js
var art1 = document.getElementById("article1").textContent;
var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

var art2 = document.getElementById("article2").textContent;
var button2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

var art3 = document.getElementById("article3").textContent;
var button3 = document.getElementById("btn3");



if (true) {
button1.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = art1;
});
}

if (true) {
button2.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = art2;
});
}

if (true) {
button3.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = art3;
});
}
```

```css
.article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="article1" class="article">
Article 1
</div>


<div id="article2" class="article">
Article 2
</div>


<div id="article3" class="article">
Article 3
</div>




<button class ="button" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button class ="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button class ="button" id="btn3">Button 3</button>

<div id="fillMe"></div>
```

Comment: Create a function accepting an index that finds the relevant data using that index.

Comment: What is the point of always-passing `if` conditions?

Comment: I was trying to test whether the button had been pressed.
What would be the alternative to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["1", "2", "3"].forEach(function(i) {
  if (true) { // I do not know why you need this though
    var content = document.getElementById("article" + i).textContent;
    var oButton = document.getElementById("btn" + i);

    oButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = content;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply make a function that accepts a number as a parameter of what article to show:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b => b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  fillMe(e.target.id.substring(e.target.id.length - 1))
}))

function fillMe(num) {
  document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = document.getElementById("article" + num).textContent;
}
```

```css
.article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="article1" class="article">
  Article 1
</div>


<div id="article2" class="article">
  Article 2
</div>


<div id="article3" class="article">
  Article 3
</div>




<button class="button" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button class="button" id="btn3">Button 3</button>

<div id="fillMe"></div>
```

Currently the Number of the article is from the id of the button that has been clicked, this can of course easily be changed to a data-article attribute or something like that

Answer (score 0):

If your article names and btn names arent going to be simply article1 , article2 ...so on and btn1,btn2...so on.

You can try this approach

You make a class ArticleMap , and maintain an array of the articleMap objects.
Then everything else is simple , just iterate through the array and initialize click listeners.

```js
class ArticleMap{

    constructor(articleId,btnId){
        this.articleId=articleId;
        this.btnId=btnId;
    }
}

var articleArr=[new ArticleMap('x','btn1'),new ArticleMap('y','btn2'),new ArticleMap('z','btn3')];
var targetId='fillMe';
var targetElement=  document.getElementById(targetId);

articleArr.forEach(function (item){
    document.getElementById(item.btnId).addEventListener('click',function (){
        targetElement.innerHTML=document.getElementById(item.articleId).textContent;
    });
});
```

```css
.article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
        <div id="x" class="article">
                Article 1
                </div>
                
                
                <div id="y" class="article">
                Article 2
                </div>
                
                
                <div id="z" class="article">
                Article 3
                </div>
                
                
                
                
                <button class ="button" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
                <button class ="button" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
                <button class ="button" id="btn3">Button 3</button>
                
                <div id="fillMe"></div>
```